# Is it possible to show non-ascii strings in json.dumps in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter Notebook, you can see non-ASCII strings in its UTF-8 forms on Python 3. But I found that this is not possible if I print the result from `json.dumps()`.

That being said, it is quite annyoing to flow the screen with the unordered texts. Is it possible to format the text yet show the UFT-8 forms in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json.dumps` keyword parameter `ensure_ascii=False`.

Example:

```
 import json

 d = {'food': 'smörgåsbord'}
 print(json.dumps(d))
 print(json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False))
```

will output

```
 {"food": "sm\u00f6rg\u00e5sbord"}
 {"food": "smörgåsbord"}
```

Comment: My guess is that it is a design choice for keeping maximum compatibility for transports that may not be binary safe, but perhaps it would have made more sense to make it False by default. Probably not possible to change this now.